# Varnish VCL Setup for Multiple Sub-Domains with V-Hosts?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, varnish, multiple-domains

Lets say for simplicity, as i'm a startup on Varnish, i have a **single** Server having `Varnish` and `Apache` together inside. There are multiple Sub-Domains in Apache as Virtual Hosts.

Lets say i have:

- sub1.example.com
- sub2.example.com
- sub3.example.com

Then i **ONLY** changed Apache's `httpd.conf` port to:

```
Listen 8080
```

Again then now my backend setting in VCL so far is:

```
backend default{
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}
```

Now my question here is:

- Is it just enough for this kind of setup? Seriously what am i missing here?
- What i'm still need to be cleard is, first, at the Apache `httpd.conf` end, is it only need to change the `Listen` value?

How about this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and also V.Host settings for each sub-domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
..
..
</VirtualHost>
```

- Do i **also need** to change those Ports to `8080` please, for Apache side?

Finally in the VCL Configuration, i am seeing such kinda following:

```
if (req.http.host == ".........com") {
    ..
}
```

.. in other forums.

- I DO NOT have this kind of setting inside my VCL
- So do i need such thing and/or seriously what do i missing for my schema please?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish will be running on the `port 80`. So, Apache should be running on any other port then `port 80`. I personally prepare to use `port 81` for Apache as `port 8080` is normal used by [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Listening Apache on `port 81`.
**httpd.conf** (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf).

```
Listen 81
NameVirtualHost *:81
```

Default configuration file for Varnish.
**default.vcl** (/etc/varnish/default.vcl).

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "81";
}
```

Virtual Host for sub1.example.net and sub2.example.net.
**vhosts.conf** (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/example.net.conf).

```
# vhost : sub1.example.net
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ...
  ServerName sub1.example.net
  ...
  <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/example.net/sub1/public_html">
    ...
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>

# vhost : sub2.example.net
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ...
  ServerName sub2.example.net
  ...
  <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/example.net/sub2/public_html">
    ...
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Awwwwn, so you mean the `VirtualHost` Ports must also be the same as Apache Port! Thankx!

Comment: Correct. Entire Apache will run on port 81 or any port you choose. Varnish will forward request from port 80 to Apache.